# .NET MVC Ajax Form keeps old input values - how to update to the model's value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a properly working ajax form in my MVC3 application except for one caveat.  After I submit the form and get the result, even though the passed in model has a different value for the input (Amount in the example below) the old value still shows up on the screen.  I attribute this to the value being saved in the DOM and overriding/preventing the new value from the model.  There are various ways to fix this by running a javascript function on one of the form events.

I would like to get feedback on what is the best way to handle this situation, preferably native to MVC and without javascript.  Here are the code snippets:

### Parent View:

```
<div id="MyContainder">
    @Html.Partial("MyPartialView", ClassContainingAmountProperty)
</div>
```

### Partial View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(actionName: "myaction",
              ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions() UpdateTargetId = "MyContainder"})
      @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Amount)
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
)
```

### Controller

```
myModel.Amount = SomeNewNumber;
return PartialView(myModel); //same partial view returned but with new amount
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As soon as I ask the question I found the answer!
[ASP.NET MVC 3 Ajax.BeginForm and Html.TextBoxFor does not reflect changes done on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217985/asp-net-mvc-3-ajax-beginform-and-html-textboxfor-does-not-reflect-changes-done-o)

You must call

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

inside the action before returning the partial view

Comment: You don't have to be so nuclear, if you're just setting `myModel.Amount` you can just do `ModelState.Remove("Amount")`

Answer (score 5):

Try putting in

```
ModelState.Clear();
```