# Html.DisplayFor and Html.EditorFor displays different values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

*I'm completely stumped.*
I'm doing a searchform in MVC2 (I've done dozen others on this project, all working fine.)
Global.asax has this route:

```
  routes.MapRoute("OnlineHelpSearchIndex",
                          "Help/Search/{expression}/{page}",
                          new { controller = "OnlineHelp", action = "Search", expression = UrlParameter.Optional, page=1 });
```

The expression is a base64 encoded string. I decode it in controller, pass it to a model which has a property named `Expression`, and display it in a PartialView in a TextBox. (Then when the user clicks a link or presses enter, I encode the string in javascript and send it to `"/Help/Search/"+value`)

I have several searchboxes built this way (each with a route `SomeModule/Search/{expression}`), and one of them is not working.

```
<%:Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Expression)%>
<%: Model.Expression %>
<%:Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Expression)%>
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Expression)%>
<%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.Expression)%>
```

**The first two display the correct expression, the other three displays the expression in the url.**
I tried hardcoding a string into the model, the first two displayed the hardcoded string, the other three displayed whatever was in the url. **How is it possible?**
(I even tried with JS disabled, so it is a server side issue)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I figured I would answer it anyway. The reason this is happening is intentional, it is due to ModelState. See this question for another case:
[Asp.net MVC ModelState.Clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775170/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-clear)

Long story short, you're POSTing form data to a controller and returning a View, and using Helpers. Therefore, MVC assumes this is a failure on validation and is returning the ModelState value, not the value of your Model data. The first two are displaying correctly because they are not editors, the other 3 are editors, so they're showing ModelState.

Either call ModelState.Clear() in the controller to blow it away, or implement another design pattern, such as POST, Redirect, GET.

Comment: Only 1 upvote is not enough for this answer. I had a sleepless night to solve this issue! Thank you, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the *name* of the `expression` parameter in both the `routes.MapRoute` and in your `OnlineHelp/Search` controller/action method:

```
routes.MapRoute("OnlineHelpSearchIndex",
                          "Help/Search/{exprs}/{page}",
                          new { controller = "OnlineHelp", action = "Search", exprs = UrlParameter.Optional, page=1 });
```

(or, if you prefer, you can change the *name* of the `Expression` property of your model).

This often happens working with form fields created by `HtmlHelper` methods such as `TextBoxFor`/`EditorFor`, when the `ViewModel` has one or more properties that share the same name of a `Router/Controller` parameter: you can easily check this looking at the generated HTML code, your input-type fields created by the `HtmlHelper` methods will most likely have an `id='Expression'` attribute which causes the whole problem.

Comment: You said that *one of them* is not working, right? The case you mentioned is working as expected: `Html.DisplayFor` and `Model.Expression` don't produce an input-type field so they aren't affected/overwritten, the other three cases do.

Comment: No, I mean `<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Expression)%>` works in all but two places.

Comment: I would need too look at the rest of the code: all I can say is, given your example, I get the same results for the above reasons. To better understand your specific issue, I suggest to set a breakpoint inside your controller's method and watch inside the `ModelState`: you should see the action parameters who most likely affecting your `TextBoxFor`(s). You can also remove them all (`Modelstate.Clear()`) or selectively (the various `keys`) before returning the model to the view, but you generally don't want to do that if you need to perform validation checks in the same Request.

Comment: Truth to be told, I got fed up with this issue more than a week ago, and written `<input type="text" id="Expression" value="<%:Model.Expression%>" />`