# Interesting Asp .net mvc example

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was trying a basic asp .net mvc project configuration explained below;

Before first submit, the result is left one in photo which is expected, after submit textbox(`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)`) and text(`@Model.Name`) shows different values as seen in right one in photo, unexpectedly; why is it so? They show different values although their model is unique.

[image]

**Model:**

```
 public class Personnel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model deneme.Models.Personnel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

    <br/>
    <br/>

    @Model.Name

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(Personnel personnel)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(personnel.Name))
     {
         personnel.Name = "Ahmet";
     }
     else
     {
         personnel.Name = personnel.Name + "server";
     }

     return View(personnel);
}
```

Comment: did you submit the form without filling the text box first time. Then it is working fine as per your code

Comment: No, the same result occurs. They are still different.

Comment: What browser are you using? I speculate that the browser might be auto-filling the form field....

Comment: I tried in multiple browsers, @Vedran solved the problem. ModelState.Clear() solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** My previous answer didn't answer your question.

If you add `ModelState.Clear()` to the controller action, it will work as you want it to.

```
public ActionResult Index(Personnel personnel)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(personnel.Name))
     {
         personnel.Name = "Ahmet";
     }
     else
     {
         personnel.Name = personnel.Name + "server";
     }

     ModelState.Clear();
     return View(personnel);
}
```

Comment: The real question is why text and textbox have different values after submit? Both is related to the same model.

Comment: @serefbilge, I misunderstood the problem, this should fix it.

Comment: Yes it worked, what is the mechanism? Is there a viewstate like thing (I think it is modelstate) ?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775170/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-clear