# Datepicker not set to value passed in the controller

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have created a datepicker using :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateTo, new { @class = "form-control DateTo" })
```

and

```
   $(".DateTo").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    autoclose: true,   
 });
```

and in the view model : 
     [Display(Name = "To")]
     public string DateTo { get; set; }

and have updated the field DateTo and passing that to view in the controller as:

```
  return view(searchviewModel);
```

In the searchviewModel, the DateTo is set to 26/11/2014.
Where as when I get the page, it is caching old values and not resetting to this value.

Any input on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelState.Clear()

[Asp.net MVC ModelState.Clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775170/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-clear).

If you retreive value via an ajax call, set the cache:false