# MVC JQuery post not returning correct partial view results

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This has got us stumped and unsure if we're encountering a bug or if there's something we're missing.

I have a part of a page which contains a dynamic number of rows, with a remove button on each that does a JQuery post to a method which returns a partial view.

```
function removeRow(panelName) {
    var deferredObject = $.Deferred();

    $.post("Resumes/RemovePanelRow", $('form').serialize() + "&panelName=" + panelName, function (partialView) {
        $('#' + panelName).html(partialView);
        $('#' + panelName).unobtrusiveUI();
        deferredObject.resolve();
    });
    return deferredObject.promise();
}
```

Clicking the remove button assigns a hidden remove value to true. The method takes the view model from the form and deletes any rows that have the value set to true. It then returns a partial view.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult RemovePanelRow(ResumeVM resume, string panelName)
{
  var allEdu = resume.Education.Where(x => x.Remove == true).ToList();
  foreach (var edu in allEdu)
  {
      resume.Education.Remove(edu);
  }

  return PartialView("PartialViews/_newEducation", resume);
}
```

Partial View _newEducation.cshtml:

```
@model ResumeTracking.Models.ViewModels.ResumeVM

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Education)
```

The EditorFor just returns a table row.

The issue is that no matter which row you click the remove button on, it deletes the last row.

When debugging and we look at the partial view results before it goes back to the jquery function, it looks correct. The model contains the last row, and only has the removed row gone. As soon as it goes back to jquery the partialView variable does not match what the method was returning.

Comment: use $.get instead of $.post

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, the fix is to add this before returning the partial view:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

The model state wasn't updated when it rendered the view.

Comment: More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775170/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-clear

Comment: And more [information here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111). The answer in the link above states its a bug. It is **not a bug** (its by design). And the correct approach is to follow the PRG pattern, not to use `ModelState.Clear()`