# Razor code producing unexpected result when looping through a list of checkboxes

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

What possible reason could there be for this razor code:

```
// ShowSelectedMembers.cshtml
@model MyApp.Models.MembersViewModel

@for (int m = 0; m < Model.Members.Count; m++)
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Members[m].Id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Members[m].FirstName" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Members[m].LastName" />
    <span>[debug-info: m = @m, id = @Model.Members[m].Id]</span>
    <span>@Model.Members[m].LastName</span>,
    <span>@Model.Members[m].FirstName</span>
}
```

to produce this HTML, when `Model.Members.Count = 1`, just containing the member with id 6653:

```
<input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Members_0__Id" name="Members[0].Id" value="6652" />
<input type="hidden" id="Members_0__FirstName" name="Members[0].FirstName" value="Peter" />
<input type="hidden" id="Members_0__LastName" name="Members[0].LastName" value="Hanson" />
<span>[debug-info: m = 0, id = 6653]</span>
<span>Swanson</span>,
<span>Lisa</span>
```

How can `Members[0].Id` have the value of 6652 in the hidden field, and 6653 inside the `<span>`?

This is the controller method for the view:

```
public IActionResult ShowSelectedMembers(MembersViewModel vm)
{
    vm.Members = vm.Members.Where(s => s.Selected).OrderBy(o => o.LastName).ThenBy(o => o.FirstName).ToList();
    return View(vm);
}
```

This is the form which sends the whole member list to the controller method:

```
// Index.cshtml
@model MyApp.Models.MembersViewModel

<form asp-action="ShowSelectedMembers">
    <button type="submit">View selection</button>
    @if (Model.Members.Any())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Members.Count; i++)
        {
            Model.Members[i].Id
            Model.Members[i].FirstName
            Model.Members[i].LastName
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Members[i].Selected" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Members[i].Id" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Members[i].FirstName" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Members[i].LastName" />
        }
    }
</form>
```

When the form data is sent to the controller method, it contains all the members in that view. The method then filters out all members with `Selected` set to `false`.

These are the ViewModels:

```
public class MembersViewModel
{
    // ... some more properties
    public List<MemberViewModel> Members { get; set; }
}

public class MemberViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    // ... some more properties
}
```

**UPDATE**

To clarify the flow of this operation:

1. The Index-view contains a form with `Selected`-checkboxes for each member in the list.
2. This form passes the whole list of members to the controller method `ShowSelectedMembers`.
3. The controller method filters out members with `Selected` set to `false`, and passes the selected members to the view `ShowSelectedMembers`.
4. The view displays the filtered list, which now has corrupted data.

**UPDATE 2**

I changed the controller method to this, creating a new instance instead of reusing the viewmodel:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSelectedMembers(MembersViewModel vmIn)
{
    List<int> memberIds = new List<int>();
    foreach (MemberViewModel member in vmIn.Members.Where(s => s.Selected).ToList())
    {
        memberIds.Add(member.Id);
    }
    List<Member> selectedMembers = await db.Members
        .Where(s => memberIds.Contains(s.Id))
        .ToListAsync();
    MembersViewModel vmOut = new MembersViewModel {
        Members = auto.Map<List<MemberViewModel>>(selectedMembers)
    };
    return View(vmOut);
}
```

... but the result is exactly the same.

**UPDATE 3**

This is so weird!

It appears to be working correctly when I change the razor code to this in `ShowSelectedMembers.cshtml`:

```
@*<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Members[i].Id" />*@
@{
    string _id = $"Members_{i}__Id";
    string _name = $"Members[{i}].Id";
    string _value = Model.Members[i].Id.ToString();
}
<input type="hidden"
       data-val="true"
       data-val-required="The Id field is required." 
       id=@_id
       name=@_name
       value=@_value />
```

I.e. manually generating the input field rather than using `asp-for`.

Comment: Is this a fresh, first-time load for the page? Or did you previously submit the form?

Comment: @Jasen The view in question is a GET called by a form submit on another view (Index). If I just select the member at the top of the list on the Index-view, it seems to work, but if I select a member further down the list, the member #1 info seems to be sent along side the selected member.

Comment: @Jasen See update at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Instead of reusing the view model as the return value, create a new instance and return that filtered collection.

Comment: @Jasen I tried, but to no avail. See update 2.

Comment: @Jasen It seems to be working with update 3. How can I make sense of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you can add `ModelState.Clear()` and it should give you the result you want.

```
public IActionResult ShowSelectedMembers(MembersViewModel vm)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    vm.Members = vm.Members.Where(s => s.Selected).OrderBy(o => o.LastName).ThenBy(o => o.FirstName).ToList();
    return View(vm);
}
```

However, I'd follow the advice here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775185/2030565 and adopt the PRG pattern -- POST the form then redirect to a GET action. You will need to store the model in the TempData store if you can't rehydrate the model from a database.